# In python def statement, Is it possible to write the for loop and return statements in one line?

Tags: python

```py
# code 1
def x():
    for i in range(3):
        print(i)
    return None

# code 2
def x():
    for i in range(3): print(i); return None

# code 3
def x():
    for i in range(3):
        print(i)
        return None

# code 4
def x():
    for i in range(3): print(i)
    return None
```

Hello. I was testing about one line statements in Python. PEP 8 doesn't recommend this, but I wonder if it's possible.

I initially tried to write code 1 in one line like code 2. However, I found that the function ended in the first loop and realized that code 2 was the same as code 3. And I've reached the code 4.

However, I wonder if it's possible to abbreviate code 4 more and write it in one line.

---

Thank you for answering. That's right. The `return None` is virtually meaningless because it can be omitted. I needed to write the questions more carefully.
But what if you want to return a processed value other than `None` as below? I abbreviated code 1 to code 2.

```py
# code 1
def x():
    processed_values = []
    for i in range(3):
        processed_values.append(i*2)
    return processed_values
print(x())

# code 2
def y():
    processed_values = []
    for i in range(3): processed_values.append(i*2)
    return processed_values
print(y())
```

Comment: That `return` statement is unnecessary to begin with.

Comment: A `rerurn None` at the last line of a function is pointless. There's an implicit `return None` if you reach the end of the function.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, you don't need to specifically call `return None` as this is done automatically. This saves us one line by default. Secondly, you can create lambda functions which are one-liner functions.

```
x = lambda num: [print(i) for i in range(num)]

# then calling your new function as normal
x(3)
```

This is functionally equivalent to:

```
def x(num):
    [print(i) for i in range(num)]
```

Comment: Those two functions are not equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using list comprehension.

```py
def code5():
    [print(i) for i in range(3)]; return None
```

The return statement here does not do anything much. So you can totally avoid it.

But most importantly, don't write code like this in any production application. This kind of coding is only going to make the things complicated and harder to understand.